# Unable to set owner of WifiP2p Direct connection between 2 devices

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have 2 Moto G devices and i am able to setup a Wifi-Direct connection between the two.

However, every time i setup the connection, by default only one device is assigned as the group-owner. Hence i can send data in only one direction. I need a way to be able to decide the role of each device. As in which device plays role of server and which one plays client role.

I looked up on the internet and following are some of the things i have tried so far. Sadly without any success-
1. Set wifiP2pConfig.groupOwnerIntent to 0 (to set role of device as client) and 15 (to set role of device as server). I did this but it has no effect. 
2. Tried invoking wifiP2pManager.removeGroup() in the onPause method of the app activity. As i read somewhere that Wifi-Direct groups with earlier assigned roles are saved to device. But again this isn't working. The callback methods are not getting invoked.

I also tried running a sample code i came across on the internet. But even there the roles of the 2 devices are static.

Has anyone successfully implemented a Wifi-Direct solution between 2 devices where the roles can be assigned? If yes then please help!